Animated Menu in react with tailwind-css
I am trying to animate the opening / closing for my sidebarmenu. I have used transition-all duraction-300 ease-in-out
Can anyone explain to me, why it doesnt work like expected please :)
Thanks in advance
 {/* Submenü */}
{menu.submenu && submenuOpen === menuIndex && open && (
    <ul
        className={`transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out overflow-hidden ${submenuOpen ? 'max-h-full' : 'max-h-0'}`}
    >
        {menu.submenuItems!.filter(filteredSubMenu).map((submenuItem, subMenuIndex) => (
            <NavLink
                to={submenuItem.path ?? location.pathname}
                key={`menu-${menuIndex}-submenu-${subMenuIndex}`}
                className={`${subMenuitemClasses} ${selectedSubmenu.menuIndex === menuIndex && selectedSubmenu.subMenuIndex === subMenuIndex ? "bg-light-white" : ""}`}
                onClick={() => {
                    updateSelectedSubmenu(menuIndex, subMenuIndex);
                    setSelectedMenu(menuIndex);
                }}
            >
                {submenuItem.icon ? submenuItem.icon : <RiDashboardFill size={20} />}
                {submenuItem.title}
            </NavLink>
        ))}
    </ul>
)}
              


The issue is in transition-all property is applied to all properties, including max-height, the transition might not work smoothly because the values are abrupt try using an a maximum height of
    className={`transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out overflow-hidden ${
        submenuOpen ? 'max-h-[500px]' : 'max-h-0'
    }`}
>

or your specific size for smoother transition.

No, that makes no differnce
